# Image and CardView shadow both not displayed when hardwareaccelerated is true or false

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-cardview

First of all let me tell you that i am new to android development and generating  dashboard page programmatically.

My Question is

In cardView i have applied shadow using setCardElevation method and in that the inner layer is

```
<LinearLayout>
ImageView (1)
ImageView (2)
View (Horizontal Line)
TextView  
</LinearLayout>
```

1) When i set hardwareaccelerated to false, able to see ImageView(1) but shadow in cardview is disappeared. 
2) When i set hardwareaccelerated to true, ImageView(1) is disappeared and shadow in cardview is displayed

I wanted to display shadow of cardview as well as ImageView(1).